# How do I add an autoincrement Counter based on Conditions and conditional reset in Google-Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, auto-increment

Have my table in Big query and have a problem getting an incremental field based on a condition.

Basically every time the score hits below 95% it returns Stage 1 for the first week. If it hits below 95% for a second straight week it returns Stage 2 etc etc. however, if it goes above 95 % the counter resets to "Good". and thereafter returns Stage 1 if it goes below 95% etc etc.

[image: Need it to look like this pic as shown in Ms Excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` -- but after assigning a group based on the count of > 95% values up to each row:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by grp order by month, week) = 1
             then 'Good'
             else concat('Stage ', row_number() over (partition by grp order by month, week) - 1)
        end) as level
from (select t.*,
             countif(score > 0.95) over (order by month, week) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select * except(grp),
  (case when Average_score >= 95 and 1 = row_number() over grps then 'Good'
    else format('Stage %i', row_number() over grps - sign(grp))
   end) as Level
from (
  select *, countif(Average_score >= 95) over (order by Month, Week) as grp
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
window grps as (partition by grp order by Month, Week)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]